# Does Ceylon allow explicit Type Casting (downcast)?

Tags: casting, type-conversion, ceylon

I know there's a concept of flow-sensitive typing in Ceylon in which we can narrow down the type of an expression by case. Is there a way to explicitly convert the type of an expression in Ceylon as in Java?

Answer (score 3):

As a statement:

```
assert(variable is NarrowType);
```

I don’t remember if there’s a recommended way to do that as an expression, but you could always put the above (plus `return variable;`) into a generic function and call it with your expression